# Notification - launch activity or Fragment which is running

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, android-notifications

In my app i am currently displaying Local Notifications, works fine.

I have a Single Activity associated with Multiple fragments, Say MainActivity associated with A,B,C fragments.

So when the notification come up, i will minimize the app and click on the notification, at that time i want the app to open (which was minimized) from where i had left.

Suppose if nothing is there or say app is killed then freshly open the app.

How can we achieve this ?

Its not happening for me here is my code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                            Intent MyIntent = new Intent();
                            MyIntent.setClassName("com.my.app.", "com.my.app.MainActivity");
                            MyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            MyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                            MyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

                            PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

                            Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                            .setTicker("My App")
                            .setContentTitle("My App")
                            .setContentText("Thank you for tap to go back!!!")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                            .setContentIntent(StartIntent)
                            .build();
                            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
                            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                    Intent MyIntent = new Intent();
                                    MyIntent.setClassName("com.my.app.", "com.my.app.MainActivity");
                                    MyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
                                    PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

                                    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                                    .setTicker("My App")
                                    .setContentTitle("My App")
                                    .setContentText("Thank you for tap to go back!!!")
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                                    .setContentIntent(StartIntent)
                                    .build();
                                    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
                                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);
```